# bluej, connects to mysql but not derby

Tags: java, connection, derby

I have the following project.  I have the same database loaded in mysql and also loaded in derby.  I'm able to connect to mysql but I get the following error message when I try to connect to derby:

```
java.sql.SQLException: Failed to start database 'school' with class loader 
sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader@b4aac2, see the next exception for details.
```

here's the code:

dbconnect.java:

```
package db;

import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.SQLException;

public class DBConnection {
    private static final String USERNAME = "rss";
    private static final String PASSWORD = "westerly";


    public static Connection getConnection(String driver, String database) 
    throws SQLException{
        String URL;
        switch (driver) {
            case "mysql":
                URL ="jdbc:" + driver + "://localhost:3306/" + database + "? 
                      useSSL=false";
                System.out.println(URL);
                return DriverManager.getConnection(URL, USERNAME, PASSWORD);
            case "derby":

                URL = "jdbc:derby:" + database ;
                System.out.println(URL);
                return DriverManager.getConnection(URL);

            default:
                System.out.println("only use mysql or derby");
                System.exit(0);
                return null;                
        }
    }
```

dbselect.java:

```
package db;

import java.lang.reflect.Method;
import tables.students;
import tables.teacher;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DatabaseMetaData;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.ResultSetMetaData;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.sql.Statement;


public class DBSelect {
    static String driver;
    static String database;
    static String table;


    public static void main(String[] args) throws SQLException  {
        table = "students";
       try(Connection con = DBConnection.getConnection(driver="derby",database="school");
             Statement stmt = 
                con.createStatement(ResultSet.TYPE_SCROLL_INSENSITIVE, 
                ResultSet.CONCUR_UPDATABLE);
             ResultSet rs1 = stmt.executeQuery("select * from " + table);
            )
        {  
            students.getStudents(rs1);
            ResultSet rs2 = stmt.executeQuery("select * from teacher");
            System.out.println("");
            teacher.getTeacher(rs2);

            rs2.first();

            try
            {rs2.getInt("fee");
              System.out.println("found");
              stmt.executeUpdate("alter table teacher drop fee  ");
            }catch(SQLException e)
            {
                System.out.println("not found");
                System.err.print(e);
                stmt.executeUpdate("alter table teacher add fee int ");
            } 


        } catch (SQLException e) {
            System.err.print(e);

        }  
    }    
}
```

Answer (score 1):

assuming that the derby database exists (if not modify jdbc url to include a 'create' option: `jdbc:derby:derbyDB;create=true` in your first run)

-- change from syserr to printstacktrace to get more info:

> ```
>     } catch (SQLException e) {
>         e.printStackTrace();
>     }
> ```

Simplest case: you have a java instance already running that has locked the DB,

Weird case: the 'log' directory is missing

Worst case: the database is corrupt.

Comment: thanks. the problem was different versions of the derby.jar